# Loading json dict into dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a json dict formatted like so

```
{"cache_age_milliseconds": 0, "rows": [{"values": [["Sonos_HXXpu71TY1g4HWWU2jXCJ8tcKu", 1483225200000, "87.61.241.100", "*null*"], 0.3605555555555556]}, {"values": [["Sonos_HXXpu71TY1g4HWWU2jXCJ8tcKu", 1483221600000, "87.61.241.100", "*null*"], 0.35888888888888887]}], "columns": [{"type": "array", "label": ["Household ID", "__hour__", "ip", "SerialNumber.Config.RoomType"]}, {"type": "number", "label": "measure_value"}]}
```

What is the fastest way to load this into a dataframe?

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid.

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: pd.read_json(xxx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong here but is this close to what you are looking for?
Because I can surely find a less dirty way to do it but the output is the important here.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"cache_age_milliseconds": 0, "rows": [{"values": [["Sonos_HXXpu71TY1g4HWWU2jXCJ8tcKu", 1483225200000, "87.61.241.100", "*null*"], 0.3605555555555556]}, {"values": [["Sonos_HXXpu71TY1g4HWWU2jXCJ8tcKu", 1483221600000, "87.61.241.100", "*null*"], 0.35888888888888887]}], "columns": [{"type": "array", "label": ["Household ID", "__hour__", "ip", "SerialNumber.Config.RoomType"]}, {"type": "number", "label": "measure_value"}]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([i["values"][0] for i in data["rows"]])
df.columns = data["columns"][0]["label"]
df.index = [i["values"][1] for i in data["rows"]]
df.index.name = data["columns"][1]["label"]
```

Results in this:

```
                                   Household ID       __hour__             ip SerialNumber.Config.RoomType
measure_value
0.360556       Sonos_HXXpu71TY1g4HWWU2jXCJ8tcKu  1483225200000  87.61.241.100                       *null*
0.358889       Sonos_HXXpu71TY1g4HWWU2jXCJ8tcKu  1483221600000  87.61.241.100                       *null*
```

Comment: Very nice solution ! ++